# How do I install the Lubuntu Software Center?

Tags: ppa, lubuntu

I'd like to install the `lubuntu software center` on lubuntu 11.10.

[Here is the launchpad project, they have a PPA](https://launchpad.net/lubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### 11.10

You can install [lubuntu-software-center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lubuntu-software-center) [image: Install lubuntu-software-center] via the following:

First, add the PPA. [The exact instructions are here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them), the PPA you need to add is this:

```
ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa
```

If you have `add-apt-repository` programe, just run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa
```

Then, you need to update your package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, you'll need to install the lubuntu software center:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
```

---

### 12.04

Lubuntu software center is in the main repositories and is part of the default Lubuntu applications. If in case you want to install it for Ubuntu or other flavours, you can use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
```

Comment: It seems no longer maintained nor supported!

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this answer, there does not seem to be any support.

But there is still another alternative, the **Gnome Software Center.**

It can be installed by: `sudo apt-get install gnome-software`.
This is in the main repositories.

**UPDATE**

Zanna (See comments) has told me that Lubuntu now comes with a software centre call Discover.
See the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYa23.jpg) to see how to open it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "there is no support". It's been a few years since this question was asked. Lubuntu now comes with a graphical software centre called [Discover](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.1/discover.html). As far as I know GNOME Software Center is still not that great after all these years so I wouldn't recommend installing it on Lubuntu. Here's a [screenshot of how to access Discover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYa23.jpg). You can rewrite your answer to mention this using my screenshot if you like

Comment: I miss the old Lubuntu Software Center from 14.04ish. It was the best of all the Software Centers.

Answer (score 0):

*According to Lubuntu there has not been an official Software Center release for Lubuntu at the moment but there is one under development by Stephen Smally that is in pre-alpha stage that you can test out. To install execute the following code inside the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
```

You can read JRG's answer above to see what each section of this code is doing.

Source: *https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-software-center/