# Installing software on Lubuntu without a browser

Tags: lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu without a browser. I can't figure out how to download and install new software on it. Should I reinstall Lubuntu?

Comment: What do you mean by "I  have installed Lubuntu without a browser"? Please clarify by editing your question? Also, add the version of Lubuntu you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[Lubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68194/how-do-i-install-the-lubuntu-software-center)** in order to install new software on your system.

- From Lubuntu 12.04 onwards, it comes preinstalled.

[image]

---

- If for some reason you don't have it, install it:

  `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center`

---

- If you are using Lubuntu 11.10 or older, the Software Center doesn't comes preinstalled. Use these commands instead to add the PPA:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-desktop/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center

---

- If you prefer the command line, you can use `apt-get` instead of the Software Center in order to install new software (but you have to know the package name).

  For example, to install firefox, type `sudo apt-get install firefox`.

Comment: @Beez - Don't forget to click the check mark next to the answer to mark your question as "answered."

Comment: I spoke too soon. I tried to install the Lubuntu Software Center using the UXTerm interface and I typed the first line. It seemed to work, but then I got a message that ultimately says "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer." Not sure what that means.

Comment: It seems to be caused by a bug on add-apt-repository (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1063350) that hasn't been fixed yet. I will look for alternatives and update my answer accondingly. Meanwhile, you can look the PPA page (https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-desktop/+archive/ppa) and see if there's any info there that could help you.

Comment: Beez, I have download the latest Lubuntu version (12.10). It comes with the software center preinstalled. I removed it and reinstalled it. I was also able to add the PPA sucesfully -- http://i.imgur.com/B8n6V.png. Your error message is probably because of another issue, why don't you ask a new question on askubuntu?